# How can I make streams return lists? (Java)

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, observablelist

I have the following list:

`ObservableList<String> Books;`

I know that if I want to have the sorted list I can write

```
public ObservableList<String> getBooks() {
    return Books;       
}
```

Now, my question may be pretty much nonsensical, but... is there a way to achieve the same result as above with streams? Something like

```
Books
    .stream()
    .sorted();
```

but then having the stream return me a sorted ObservableList?
I'm just starting to learn about streams and don't know much about it yet, so I was wondering if something like that is possible.

Comment: Your first code isn't even closely related to _sorting_ so you don't need Java streams for that.

Comment: Your first code block is an accessor/getter that returns an `ObservableList<String>` - it does nothing else. Your second code block seems to sort a stream, but I'm not sure. Your question is confusing/doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear, my question was basically how to convert a stream to an observable list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Side note: `Books` is the wrong naming convention for a variable; use `books`.*

---

This is indeed possible, using [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)s. Or even [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html). Assuming `ObservableList` is a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of some sort, you can do the following:

```
ObservableList<String> hereYouGo = Books.stream()
      .sorted()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ObservableList::new));
```

Where `ObservableList::new` is the supplier of an empty `ObservableList` for the collector. Change this if that's not how your class works.

Comment: This one worked, thanks a lot! I just had to change ObservableList::new to FXCollections::observableArrayList in my class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Collector` to turn a Stream back into a List. If you don't care what type of List it is, there is a built-in collector:

```
getBooks().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If it needs to be an ObservableList, you need to invent your own Collector:

```
getBooks().stream().sorted
    .collect(ObservableList::new, ObservableList::add, ObservableList::addAll);
```

Comment: [`toCollection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) is also a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the list in place, there's no need for streams, you can just call

```
Collections.sort(books);
```

If you want to return a new sorted `ObservableList<Book>` using streams, you can do this:

```
ObservableList<Book> sortedBooks = books.stream()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
```